# Несколько Request в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем добрый вечер.

При разработке возник такой вопрос.
Можно ли создавать несколько классов Request для проверки пришедших данных от пользователя?

У меня есть форма добавления ингредиента для рецепта и при отправки формы я проверяю данные в IngredientRequest. Код ниже:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'ingredientName' => 'required|string'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'ingredientName.required' => 'Field ingredient name is empty',
            'ingredientName.string' => 'Field ingredient name is not a string'
        ];
    }
```

Теперь делаю форму для обновления количества ингредиента. Мне же нужно теперь создать новый Request, например UpdateIngredientRequest (или как правильно нужно назвать Request для разных задач?) ?

Подскажите правильную структуру:

1. Нужно ли создавать под каждый запрос (обновление, добавление) разные Request?
2. Как правильно их назвать? Может сделать такую вот структуру папок(app/HTTP/Request/Ingredient/CreateIngredientRequest, UpdateIngredientRequest)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли создавать несколько классов Request ...

Видимо для этого и было введено понятие *Form request* (запрос из формы), а в документации посвящен целый раздел по [созданию классов](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests), в которых описана логика валидации. Это позволяет сохранять контроллеры в "чистоте".

**Создание**

Учитывая ваше желание структурного разделения, вам необходимо выполнить следующие команды:

```
php artisan make:request Ingredient\StoreIngredient

php artisan make:request Ingredient\UpdateIngredient
```

Будут созданы два файла с расположением в директории `app/Http/Requests/Ingredient`.

**Подключение**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Ingredient;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreIngredient;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateIngredient;

class IngredientController extends Controller
{
  // ... code

  public function store(StoreIngredient $request)
  {
    // ... code
  }

  public function update(UpdateIngredient $request, Ingredient $ingredient)
  {
    // ... code
  }

  // ... code
}
```

---

Порой необходимо по-быстрому создать какой-нибудь фильтр или передать параметры сортировки для индексной страницы:

```
php artisan make:request Ingredient\IndexIngredient
```

```
// ... code

class IngredientController extends Controller
{
  public function index(IndexIngredient $request)
  {
    // ... code
  }
}
```