# Нужно ли делать валидацию всех параметров запроса для каждого маршрута используя Request класс?

Tags: laravel, api

Недавно начал изучать Laravel. Прочитал что хорошей практикой является создание Request классов с правилами валидации. Насколько я понял их создают когда нужно сохранить что то в БД, но что насчет случаев когда есть GET маршрут example.com/friends/{id} нужно ли создавать Request класс и прописывать в нем правило валидации?

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|integer'
        ];
    }
```

Предполагаю что да иначе если передать строку в качестве GET параметра id, то api попытается выполнить запрос к БД и вернет в моем случае ошибку 500.
Если да, то нужно для всех запросов GEТ, POST, PUT, DELETE создавать отельный Request класс с правилами валидации? Возможно если валидация маленькая по типу примера выше, то стоит ее оставить в контроллере, а если объемная, то лучше создать Request класс.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/999393/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше это ограничение прописать в роутах:

```
Route::get('friends/{id}', ...)->where(['id' => '[0-9]+');
```

Если вы используете resource(), то можно и для него прописать ограничение, если задать имя параметру:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['parameters' => [
   'user' => 'id'
]]);

Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
```

> Возможно если валидация маленькая по типу примера выше, то стоит ее оставить в контроллере.

Валидировать параметры роута в методе контроллера - плохая практика.
Некорректный запрос не должен доходить до контроллера.

Comment: Все было так просто. А я искал репозитории с проектами на Laravel и думал почему в них создают Request классы только когда собираются записывать данные с формы в БД, а get параметры не понятно где проверяют.